# Can't center jdialog in jframe

Tags: java

I can't center my jdialog in my jframe. I've tried to do this but it doesn't work:

```
public void open(){
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(Main.instance.frame);
    }
```

Tell me if you need any more code! Thanks for your help!

Main:

```
public class Main {

    public static Main instance;

    public JXFrame frame;
    public JXPanel panel;
    public String name = "";

    // Windows
    public WindowCreateProject windowCreateProject;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        instance = new Main();
        instance.start();
    }

    public void init() {
        // Init components
        Icons.createIcons();
        MainMenu.init();
        // JXFrame
        frame = new JXFrame();
        panel = new JXPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        panel.setLayout(new CardLayout());
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1980, 1080));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JXFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // Add components
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(MainMenu.menuBar);
        // JXFrame
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setTitle(name);
        // Create windows
        windowCreateProject = new WindowCreateProject();
        update();
    }

    public void update(){
        while(frame.isActive()){

        }
    }

    public void start() {
        init();
    }

    public void stop() {
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

WindowCreateProject:

```
public class WindowCreateProject extends Window {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public JTextField nameField;
    public JButton createProject;
    public JButton cancel;

    public WindowCreateProject() {
        super("Create New Project");
        // Setup components
        nameField = new JTextField();
        nameField.setSize(100, nameField.getHeight());
        createProject = new JButton("Create Project", Icons.ok);
        cancel = new JButton("Cancel", Icons.cancel);
        // Add components
        panel.add(nameField);
        panel.add(createProject);
        panel.add(cancel);
        addActionListeners();
    }

    public void addActionListeners(){
        cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                close();
            }
        });
    }

    public void close(){
        nameField.setText("");
        this.setVisible(false);
    }

}
```

Window:

```
public class Window extends JDialog {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public JPanel panel;

    public Window(String title) {
        panel = new JPanel();   
        this.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 400));
        this.add(panel);
        this.pack();    
        this.setTitle(title);
    }

    public void open(){
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(Main.instance.frame);
    }

}
```

MenuMain:
public class MainMenu {

```
public static JMenuBar menuBar;
public static JMenu menuProjects;
public static JMenu menuOptions;
public static JMenu menuHelp;

// Projects menu items
public static JMenuItem createProject;
public static JMenuItem myProjects;
public static JMenuItem saveProject;
public static JMenuItem saveProjectAs;
public static JMenuItem exportResourcepackTo;
public static JMenuItem exportResourcepackToMinecraft;
public static JMenuItem exit;

public static void init(){
    // Init menu
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menuBar.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    menuProjects = new JMenu("Projects");
    menuOptions = new JMenu("Options");
    menuHelp = new JMenu("Help");
    createMenuItems();
    // Add components
    menuBar.add(menuProjects);
    menuBar.add(menuOptions);
    menuBar.add(menuHelp);
    // Add menu items to project menu
    menuProjects.add(createProject);
    menuProjects.add(myProjects);
    menuProjects.add(saveProject);
    menuProjects.add(saveProjectAs);
    menuProjects.addSeparator();
    menuProjects.add(exportResourcepackTo);
    menuProjects.add(exportResourcepackToMinecraft);
    menuProjects.addSeparator();
    menuProjects.add(exit);
    createActionListeners();
}

public static void createMenuItems(){
    createProject = new JMenuItem("Create project", Icons.createProject);
    myProjects = new JMenuItem("My projects", Icons.myProjects);
    saveProject = new JMenuItem("Save project");
    saveProjectAs = new JMenuItem("Save project as");
    exportResourcepackTo = new JMenuItem("Export resourcepack to");
    exportResourcepackToMinecraft = new JMenuItem("Export resourcepack to minecrat");
    exit = new JMenuItem("Exit", Icons.cancel);
}

public static void createActionListeners(){
    // Project menu
    createProject.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Main.instance.windowCreateProject.open();
        }   
    });
    exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Main.instance.stop();
        }   
    });
}
```

}

Comment: `"Tell me if you need any more code!"` -- we need **less**. You've posted a ton of code, most completely unrelated to your problem, and this risks swamping us with unnecessary code, possibly preventing us from seeing your problem and being able to help you.

Comment: Please understand that we don't want to see your whole program, especially if it's larger than 60 lines long, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem, in other words, a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please see edits to answer.

Comment: ..................hello?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 2):

Order matters. So change this:

```
public Window(String title) {
    panel = new JPanel();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(Main.instance.frame);
    this.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 400));
    this.pack();    
    this.add(panel);
    this.setTitle(title);
}
```

to this:

```
public Window(String title) {
    panel = new JPanel();

    // nope:
    // this.setLocationRelativeTo(Main.instance.frame);

    this.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setTitle(title);
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 400));
    this.add(panel);  // add **before** packing
    this.pack();    // have to be **after** this!!

    // yep!
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(Main.instance.frame);

    // set visible true here
}
```

In your code above, you're **still** using the wrong order. You've got this:

```
public void open() {
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(Main.instance.frame);
}
```

When you should be using this:

```
public void open() {
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(Main.instance.frame); // !!
    this.setVisible(true);
    // !!this.setLocationRelativeTo(Main.instance.frame);
}
```

Also, it doesn't appear that you're setting the JDialog's owner window to the main JFrame, and to do this, you would need to use the appropriate super JDialog constructor, one that accepts a JFrame parameter.